# how to use cpulimit with additional php arguments?

Tags: php, bash, getopt

I am using `cpulimit` with no problem like this:

```
cpulimit -l 60 -z -v php /path/to/file/file.php
```

But I want to add another arguments to this call like:

```
cpulimit -l 60 -z -v php /path/to/file/file.php id=0
```

And try to get its value using `getopt`.

But the problem is I'm getting empty array if I try to display the options like so:

```
$options = getopt('acc');
```

Any thoughts on this? Tia

Answer (score 0):

[getopt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) is searching for flags, like `--id=2` so it will be mix with cpulimit
just use [argv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) and [argc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php):

```
<?php

var_dump($argv);
```

result:

```
cpulimit -l 60 -z -v php a.php id=2
Launching php a.php id=2 with limit 60
Throttling process 7588
8 CPUs detected.
Warning: Cannot change priority. Run as root or renice for best results.
Process 7588 detected

%CPU    work quantum    sleep quantum   active rate
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "a.php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "id=2"
}
```

Comment: thanks but how to go about getting the value of the id?

Comment: you can just pars the second $argv

Comment: @silent_coder14, ugly, but it works: var_dump((explode("=", $argv[1] ?? ''))[1] ?? '');

Comment: cron just running process inside cli. so it should, why not?